# Can I start a youtube channel and earn from ad-sense(if any) while being in US on F1 or H1 Visa?

Tags: f1-student-visa, h-1b-visa

I am currently working on F1 STEM OPT, and waiting on my H1B approval. I would like to start a YouTube channel to post tech videos, game play and some other content through different channels. This would be a good way to learn and save up my skills.

If I were to earn any more through Google AdSense is this considered illegal? This is not exactly opting for a job right?

The answers from google are going both ways and I am a little confused.

Thanks for reading through, any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to read the answers to this similar question https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/54052/can-an-f1-student-working-on-opt-with-a-stem-extension-earn-unrelated-self-emplo?rq=1

Comment: Also, ir might be helpful to ask this question on WebApps SE because they discuss Google AdSense specifically